# Should exclusions be handled in the child pom or parent pom?

Tags: maven

I am commonly in this situation where I am working on a couple of projects that all depend on the same parent pom. We handle all of our dependency versions and exclusions in the dependencyManagement section of the parent pom. The child poms will specify the dependencies they need but they will use the version from the parent.

When we place an exclusion on a jar, it is generally because we are wanting to get a different version of that jar from somewhere else (typically a different jar we depend on).

However, I ran into a problem. Lets say you have two jars A and B in the parent that depend on different versions of jar C. Someone working on a child project may need both jars A and B and then might go into the parent, excluding jar C from jar B. This may work out fine for them. However, someone else who is working on a different child project may only depend on jar B and now their project might get a NoClassDefFoundError at runtime after they pick up the latest parent code due to losing jar C. Now, maybe a 3rd person who is later working on a different child project decides they need jar B (and not jar A) so they add jar B. If they don't pay careful attention, they may not realize that they don't have jar C which is needed by jar B. At runtime they might get a NoClassDefFoundError.

As you can see, any child project that needs both jar A and jar B are fine but any child project that needs only jar B needs to remember to add jar C to their pom too.

Is it better practice to only do exclusions in the child pom? Or should I continue trying to have exclusions in the parent pom and make sure to just look closely at the exclusions and add additional dependencies to the child pom as needed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dependencyManagement` in the parent for versions only, not for exclusions (and not for scope). As you point out yourself, adding exclusions in the parent can lead to situations where other developers (and maybe even yourself at a later point in time) get confused about why they don't get the necessary and expected transitive dependencies.

Regarding:

> When we place an exclusion on a jar, it is generally because we are
>   wanting to get a different version of that jar from somewhere else
>   (typically a different jar we depend on).

You can enforce the correct version for these transitive dependencies in your parent pom as well to avoid exclusions for the reason you give here. The downside is of course that you must remember to update those versions when you update the version of the dependent library. This is how we manage our project with >200 poms, and I must say it's far better than figuring out where to add excludes to hopefully get the correct version of all the dependencies.